# How to implement Matrix left division in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I am converting the Matlab code to the OpenCV-C code and I need to implement matrix left division. How can it be done in OpenCV? For example, A \ B, A is 18 x 12 matrix and B is 18 x 1 matrix. How can I make it work in OpenCV?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is already implemented in OpenCV by the name of [`cvSolve`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=solve#solve) or [`cv::solve`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=solve#solve)

Comment: Only think to remember here is to be sure to have the flag "DECOMP_NORMAL" set with cv::solve().